# How to merge table cells when adjacent cell empty?

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm looking for a way to merge cells, but only when a condition is true. Other suggestions to my problem are fine, too.

Background: I need to create a Jasper report for which I got a design/layout specification. All data is provided through a single stored procedure.

The layout is mostly a simple table with data, but some rows differ from the rest and contain some sort of interim report data (that's not calculated from the previous values). Those rows also differ in the row layout. Number of rows before and after are dynamic.

Example:

```
------------------------------------
| data | data | data | data | data |
------------------------------------
| data | data | data | data | data |
------------------------------------
| data | data | data | data | data |
------------------------------------
| some text   | abc         |  def |
------------------------------------
| data | data | data | data | data |
------------------------------------
| different text     |         xyz |
------------------------------------
```

The procedure delivers all of this data in a single data set, including the text of those special rows. For those cell that should be merge with their left adjacent cell the procedure returns NULL, all other cells always contain some sort of data.

Now I could need some help to actually merge those cells. If there are other/better ways to achieve the given layout, feel free to suggest those.
Unfortunately I have no control over the stored procedure, but slight alterations might be possible.

Comment: You can use conditional styles or printWhen expression

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to do that to achieve the desired result? printWhen seems to do nothing (cell is empty either way, but doesn't "vanish" so the adjacent cell can take it's place), neither could I find a style element that allows me to "break the border" of a cell.

Comment: Are you using the jr:table component or textField's in detail band?

Comment: I'm currently using a table component because I need to put more than one of those data tables into my report, but if it's easier to do this with text fields I guess I could switch to using them with subreports.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't provide more information on what I've tried, my Jasper knowledge is pretty basic -  I've actually never used it before. It's one of those legacy projects. "We need you to expand this with those functions and you need to use those tools."
Unfortunately I wasn't able to find much about this specific problem. Some similar with the suggestion to use a CrossTable element and not much more information, but what I've read about this element I doesn't seem to work with the data I get from the procedure.

Comment: @Aki unfortunately there is no simple way to do colspan like that in jasper report to you would need to use the detail band with multiple textFields and printWhenExpression. Dynamic height is easy, dynamic width no.

Comment: Well, that's too bad. Anyways, thanks for your input. I've been able to alter the specification and procedure a bit. With that it's a bit easier to implement the different types of row layouts using your textField suggestion in a subreport.